# Fortran runtime error: Index '645778864' of dimension 1 of array 'tstar' above upper bound of 24

Tags: arrays, runtime, fortran90

I wrote this program to test another code, it compiles well but at runtime i receive these kind of errors:

```
Fortran runtime error: Index '645778864' of dimension 1 of array 'tstar' above upper bound of 24
```

my code takes as input a data file (6 columns and 24 rows corresponding to different times of the day), reads them and uses them in the subroutine "profile" to extract new parameters (u and tp). I called the number of elements (24) of the vectors corresponding to the 6 columns taken as inputs and do not understand why there are these errors.

```
program test
 implicit none

 character(len=12) filein,fileout
 integer :: row,ih,i
 real :: k = 0.4
 real :: z0 = 0.0012
 real, dimension(6) :: z=(/0.5,1.,2.,4.,8.,16./)
 real, dimension(6) :: u
 real, dimension(2) :: teta,tp
 real, dimension(2) :: dt
 real, dimension(24) :: L,tstar,Ho,ustar,tk
 real :: g = 9.81

 write(*,'(2x,''File di input .......''/)')
 read(*,'(a12)') filein
 write(*,'(2x,''File di output........''/)')
 read(*,'(a12)') fileout


 open(unit=60,File=filein)
 open(unit=80,File=fileout)

 write(80,*)

  do row = 1,24    
  read(60,*) ih,ustar,tk,(dt(i),i=1,2),Ho

  teta(1) = dt(1) + tk(row)
  teta(2) = (dt(2)-dt(1)) + teta(1)

  call profile(ustar,Ho,u,teta,tp)
  write(80,*) u,tp

 enddo

close(60)
close(80)


end program test

subroutine profile(ustar,Ho,u,teta,tp)
 implicit none
 integer :: i,j,row
 integer :: N = 6
 real, dimension(24), intent(in) :: ustar,Ho
 real, dimension(24) :: tstar,L,tk
 real, dimension(6),intent(out) :: u
 real, dimension(6) :: z=(/0.5,1.,2.,4.,8.,16./)
 real, dimension(2),intent(out) :: tp
 real, dimension(2) :: teta
 real :: k = 0.4
 real :: z0 = 0.0012
 real :: g = 9.81

 tstar = 0.
 L = 0.

 tstar(row) = -(Ho(row)/(1200.*ustar(row)))
 L(row) = (tk(row)*ustar(row))/(k*g*tstar(row))

 ! convective situation
 do i=1,6
  u(i) = (ustar(row)/k)*(alog(z(i)/z0) +1. - (1. - (16.*(z(i)/L(row))))**0.25)
  if(i.le.2) then
  tp(i) = teta(i) + (tstar(row)/k)*(alog(z(i+2)) - (2.*(alog(0.5 + (0.5*(sqrt(abs(1.-(16.*(z(i+2)/L(row)))))))))))
  endif

 enddo


end
```

The input file consists of 6 columns, the first of integers (hours of the day), the other corresponding to the actual quantities that are read from the row:

```
read(60,*) ih,ustar,tk,(dt(i),i=1,2),Ho
```

The code is written in Fortran90 and i use gfortran to compile. I'm not an expert Fortran so I ask you not to use terms that are too specific.

ok I assigned "row" as an argument of the subroutine but now it gives me error as:

```
At line 29 of file test.f90 (unit = 60, file = 'inputver.dat')
Fortran runtime error: End of file
```

why does it give me this error?

Comment: Always use tag [tag:fortran] and only add the version when necessary to distinguish that your question is specific. For example that you cannot use Fortran 2008 but only Fortran 90.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have never set `row`, so it contains some arbitrary value, in your case `645778864`. From your code I read that `tstar` is of length `24`, hence the error.

You should specify `row` e.g. as a dummy argument to your subroutine.